# Predicting accelerating object collisions in a friction-less environment

Tags: derivatives, physics

#### Background

I'm building a simple game where two ships are launching missiles at each other in space.

Stuff got complicated when the ships started moving in a friction-less environment and the missiles naturally needed to do the same thing.

#### Premises

1. A missile has a constant acceleration and is trying to hit a moving target in a friction-less environment.
2. Target is also constantly accelerating in the same friction-less environment.
3. The friction-less environment is only 2 dimensional
4. There is no gravitation affecting the missile

#### Question

What math should I use to determine the direction the missile should jolt in?

#### What i have right now

I've implemented [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/25292) which works quite alright. I am not 100% sure of what a, b, c etc means and not sure which math is actually implemented here.

I modified above linked answer by making the missile mimic its targets jolts and adding its own on top of those. It is an ugly solution to say the least.

#### Problem with current solution

The current solution requires to know the speed of the missile.

The missile is constantly accelerating, and it has no top speed.

Unless I know how far the missile will travel, *I cannot know the average speed.*

Above solution requires that I know the speed of the projectile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the physics:

In one dimension $x(t)=x_0+v_0t+at^2/2$. $x_0$ is the initial coordinate, $v_0$ is the initial velocity.
For your problem, you have two directions (along $x$ and along $y$) and two objects (target will be denoted by subscript T, missile by subscript M)
$$
x_T(t)=x_{T,0}+v_{T,x,0} t+a_{T,x}t^2/2\\
y_T(t)=y_{T,0}+v_{T,y,0} t+a_{T,y}t^2/2\\
x_M(t)=x_{M,0}+v_{M,x,0} t+a_{M,x}t^2/2\\
y_M(t)=y_{M,0}+v_{M,y,0} t+a_{M,y}t^2/2\\
$$ 
It is possible that some of your initial velocities or positions are 0, but I wrote the equations for the general case. On the right side of these equations you know the initial positions and velocities, both $x$ and $y$ components, for both target and missile, and the two components of target acceleration.

When the missile hits the target $x_T(t)=x_M(t)$ and $y_T(t)=y_M(t)$. You can then rewrite these equations as:
$$
(x_{T,0}-x_{M,0})+(v_{T,x,0}-v_{M,x,0})t+(a_{T,x}-a_{M,x})t^2/2=0\\
(y_{T,0}-y_{M,0})+(v_{T,y,0}-v_{M,y,0})t+(a_{T,y}-a_{M,y})t^2/2=0
$$
Now you have two equations, with unknowns $t, a_{M,x},a_{M,y}$. If you don't have another equation, you have an infinite number of solutions. You can hit the target at any time $t>0$ if you have enough acceleration. If you know the absolute value for the acceleration of the missile $a_M$, you can add it as one of your equations $a_M^2=a_{M,x}^2+a_{M,y}^2$. Or if you are interested in the direction $\theta$ with respect to the $x$ direction, you can write $a_{M,x}=a_M\cos(\theta)$ and $a_{M,y}=a_M\sin(\theta)$. Now you need to solve these equations, by eliminating $t$. Note that since this is a quadratic equation you will need to choose the positive solution. You might have multiple solutions anyway, or none if your acceleration is too small.

Once you get the solution for $a_{M,x}$ and $a_{M,y}$, you can use the first 4 equations to plot the trajectories as a function of time.